# How to connect datagrid and mysql database through adodb

Tags: mysql, vb.net, adodb

I have to display a table in data grid in vb.net(visual studio 2008) using adodb from mysql.
but the following code not working .(No error are shown)
please help
I opted adodb due to error,even after many attempts ,using mysqldataadpter

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
'Imports MySql.Data.Types
'Imports MySql.Data.VisualStudio
'Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class Form3
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mrs2 As New ADODB.Recordset


    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String


    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       
        sconnect = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=stockauto;User=root;Password=;"
        If Conn.State = 1 Then
            Conn.Close()
        End If
        Conn.Open(sconnect)
        sql2 = "SELECT * From STOCK"
        mrs.Open(sql2, Conn)
        If mrs.State = 1 Then
            mrs.Close()
        End If
        mrs.Open(sql2, Conn)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = mrs
        DataGridView1.Refresh()


    End Sub
```

Comment: *"I opted adodb due to error,even after many attempts ,using mysqldataadpter"*. That was a terrible, TERRIBLE idea. If ADO.NET didn't work it is because you did it wrong. You should have asked for help with that mistake. Now you've just made a bad situation worse and it's still not working. For all we know, you're making the same mistake now that you did then. Don't use technology that has been obsolete for 20 years.

Comment: Thank you friend for your valuable advice.The error for ado.net connection is -The given key was not present in the dictionary.- in the following code ` Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=stockauto;User=root;Password=;"
        'Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource
        'Try
        MysqlConn.Open()` The error is on the last line

Comment: It is not the place to post that in the comments on a different question. You should post a separate question specific to that issue with all the information relevant to that issue and only the information relevant to that issue. Comments are not the place to post long code snippets at the best of times as they are hard to read.

Comment: Ok I tried.But banning to ask question appears. Sorry

Comment: I don't know what that means. It appears that you just wrote a bad connection string and didn't bother to learn what a proper Connector/Net connection string looks like. If you had done that, you wouldn't have wasted all that time and effort on the dead end of ADODB. You can learn how to write a proper connection string [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the connection string. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

I used the simplest example. Replace `yourUserID` and `yourPassword` with the real values.

Get rid of all the ADODB and ODBC stuff. This code uses ADO.net

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that database objects are closed and disposed.

```
Private MySqlConnStr As String = "Server=localhost;Database=stockauto;Uid=yourUserId;Pwd=yourPassword;"
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetStockData()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
Private Function GetStockData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(MySqlConnStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * From STOCK", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I tried it .But  it caused an error-The given key was not present in the dictionary. @ cn.open().Please help!

Comment: @SajithMU Your connection string is still not correct.. Can you post exactly what the connection string is except use a fake password and user id.

Comment: @ MARY ,Thanks a lot.Finally it works!The problem was due to version of mysql connector. I tried another version and now it works.Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

ADODB is the old mechanism from pre-.Net VB. It exists only for backwards compatibility with old code and *should not be used for new development*.

Try this, which uses the updated ADO.Net:

```
      ' Don't use the root account to connect to the database!
Private sconnect As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=stockauto;User=root;Password=;"

Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   
    Dim data As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(sconnect), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock", cn), _
          da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        da.Fill(data)
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = data
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it but caused an error- Keyword not supported. Parameter name: driver- in the line -cn As New MySqlConnection(sconnect)- These were used Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Imports MySql.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Comment: I also tired another way.But it also caused error -The given key was not present in the dictionary.- in the following code ` Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=stockauto;User=root;Password=;"
        'Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource
        'Try
        MysqlConn.Open()` The error is on the last line